# Can't launch Steam on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: steam

I try to launch Steam from the terminal but I get this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: r600_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: r600
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

to fix it simply open the terminal and run these commands

```
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
rm ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
```

Steam should then work properly.But make sure not to install the proprietary AMD drivers as they are very bad for the stability of the OS compared to the open source drivers.If you are getting low performance with the open source drivers then simply upgrade the Mesa version by adding the xorg edgers ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

After that type this in order to upgrade the Mesa version

```
sudo apt-get update & sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then reboot and the new Mesa driver should be loaded.